# Slideshow Stops after last image

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

My slideshow works, however when the last image is reached it stays stuck there and won't continue, when I refresh the page it starts at the first image again and works untill the last image is reached.

HTML:

```
       <div class="slider">

        <img src="slide1_hamburger.jpg" class="slide_image slider_active"></img>
        <img src="slide2_eetzaal.jpg" class="slide_image"></img>
        <img src="slide3_carpaccio.jpg" class="slide_image"></img>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide_image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}


.slider_active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Jquery:

```
function slideSwitch() {
        var $slider_active = $('div.slider IMG.slider_active');
        var $next = $slider_active.next();    

        $next.addClass('slider_active');

        $active.removeClass('slider_active');
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Does anyone have an idea why it stops at the last image and won't continue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unused **$active** object in the code. If you remove the class .slider_active and one more correction **your setInterval only works for mozila if you want all browsers supports**

use like

```
setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000 );
```

just use

```
$('.slider_active').removeClass('slider_active');
```

your code be

```
function slideSwitch() {
        var $slider_active = $('div.slider IMG.slider_active');
        var $next = $slider_active.next();  
        $('.slider_active').removeClass('slider_active');
        $next.addClass('slider_active');
        if($next.length == 0){  // for cyclic rotation
         $('div.slider IMG:eq(0)').addClass('slider_active');
        }
 }
$(function() {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
});
```

[**Fiddle sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/v37t409z/)

Answer (score 2):

It stops at the last image because the routine tries to get the `.next()` element, which is not there.

You need to add a check to see if `$next` actually exists and then go back to the start if it doesn't. Something like:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $slider_active = $('div.slider IMG.slider_active');
    var $next = $slider_active.next();    

    if(!$next) {
        $next = $('div.slider IMG')[0];
    }

    $next.addClass('slider_active');

    $slider_active.removeClass('slider_active');
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: I try to implant it but the  $next = $('div.slider IMG')[0]; make it not go back to the start

Comment: A made a correction to the last line in `slideSwitch()` function, it was using an incorrect variable name

Comment: Sadly after the last image it just fades to a white screen :(

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is point the $next variable to the first image once it has gotten to the end of the images.

replace `var $next = $slider_active.next();` with

```
var $next =  $slider_active.next().length ? $slider_active.next() : $('div.slider IMG:first');
```

Comment: This make the whole thing not work anymore :(, I understand that their is something wrong with the $next variable but this solution sadly does not work

Comment: Ah, I forgot a `.`. Updated my awnser `$slider_activenext()` should have been `$slider_active.next()`

Comment: Thanks for the update, now it works but it still stops after the last image :/